# java generics compilation error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I've the following generic class:

```
public class GenericClass<E,T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    public static <E, T extends Comparable<T>> GenericClass<E, T> create()
    {
        return new GenericClass<E, T>();
    }

    private GenericClass()
    {
    }
}
```

And this is how I simply use it:

```
GenericClass<MyClass, Double> set = GenericClass.create();
```

Eclipse compilation shows no errors, however - building with ant provides the following error:

```
MyClass.java:19: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) E,T exist so that GenericClass<E,T> conforms to GenericClass<MyClass,java.lang.Double>
[javac] found   : <E,T>GenericClass<E,T>
[javac] required: GenericClass<MyClass,java.lang.Double>
[javac]             GenericClass<MyClass, Double> set = GenericClass.create();
```

Thanks!

Comment: And SortedSetByDoubleValue is...?

Comment: Fixed... I've changed the class names for simplicity

Comment: My suggestion is to not use the same names for generic types in the static method create and the class. Although it's technically legal, it might lead to some crazy mistakes hard to spot. I would strongly suggest replacing E,T with E2 and T2 (or whatever) in the whole create() definition.

Comment: for best results with subclasses, the bound should be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this:

```
      GenericClass<String, Double> set = GenericClass.<String,Double>create();
```

The Eclipse compiler and javac differ in their tolerance.

Comment: So how does Google's Sets.newHashSet() (for example) works? What is the difference?

Comment: @duduamar: `newHashSet()` is less complex: it has no restriction on the two type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `GenericClass.create()` bears no indication of type, so the compiler cannot infer the real type of E and T. You need to change the prototype of your function to help the compiler.

The simplest way is to pass the classes.

Example:

```
public class GenericClass<E,T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public static <E, T extends Comparable<T>> GenericClass<E, T> create(Class<E> e, Class<T> t) {
        return new GenericClass<E, T>();
    }

    private GenericClass() {
    }
}

GenericClass<MyClass, Double> set = GenericClass.create(MyClass.class, Double.class);
```

Comment: The compiler *should* be able to infer the type. And it is possible (as the eclipse compiler clearly demonstrates). I've found similar bugs where `javac` wasn't able to infer the types and the eclipse compiler was able to. Each time I've filed bugs for it (with both Eclipse and Sun/Oracle) it turned out to be `javac` that was at fault.

Comment: Yes... but javac is the reference ;-) Anyway, I learned something new thanks to Grzegorz.